# How to access the div element with class and attach the popup to it using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i am trying to create a popupdialog to be shown when user clicks on a button. for that i am using portal.

i want it to look like in the picture below,
[image]

So basically, when user clicks on the add button i want the popup dialog to display like in the picture above.

in the popup component i want to render overlay with children. and when user clicks on overlay div the popup should close.

I have something that kind of works without using Portal and is like below,

below is my code that is without using Portal,

```
function Parent({isDialogOpen, setDialogOpen, setSomething}: Props) {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = React.useState(false);
    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        if (setIsDialogOpen) setIsDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
        if (setSomething) setSomething(isDialogOpen);
        setIsClicked(!isClicked);
    };
    return (
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>click</button>
        {isDialogOpen && isClicked &&
            <Overlay>
                <Dialog>
                    //some divs
                </Dialog>
            </Overlay>
        }
    );
}


const Overlay = styled.div`
    position: fixed;
    padding-top:60px;
    bottom: 40px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`;

 const Dialog = styled.div`
     padding: 16px;
     width: 384px;
     max-height: calc(100% - 200px);
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
 `;
```

Now i am rewriting above using portal like below,

```
function Parent({isDialogOpen, setDialogOpen, setSomething}: Props) {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = React.useState(false);
    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        if (setIsDialogOpen) setIsDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
        if (setSomething) setSomething(isDialogOpen);
        setIsClicked(!isClicked);
    };
    return (
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>click</button>
        {isDialogOpen && isClicked &&
            <Popup setSomething={setSomething} setIsDialogOpen={setIsDialogOpen} setIsClicked= 
            {setIsClicked}>
                <Dialog>
                    //some divs
                </Dialog>
            </Overlay>
        }
    );
}

function Popup({setIsClicked, setSomething, setIsDialogOpen, children}: Props) {
    return ReactDom.createPortal(
        <>
            <Overlay
                onClick={() => {
                    if (setIsDialogOpen) setIsDialogOpen(false);
                    if (setSomething) setSomething(true);
                    setIsClicked(false);
                }}
            >
                {children}
            </Overlay>
        </>,
        //dont know what to pass here
    );
}
```

Basically as seen in picture above, i want to render the overlay with dialog.

now in popup component i want to create div with classname 'popup' and find the div element with class navbar and attach this div popup to the navbar div

and pass this div element with class popup in the reactDOM.createPortal.

i am new to react and not sure how to do this. could someone help me with this.

thanks.

Comment: this is not how you use portal. you need to mount a portal into an existing dom node, same as you render your app with `ReactDom.render( targetNode, componentTree )`. so for example, you may mount some element in your main app, like `<div id="popup-dialog" />`, so you would render into that like `ReactDom.createPortal( document.getElementById('popup-dialog'), <MyComponent />);` one thing you need to think about with portals, is that the element you are rendering to in the dom must be there before you render. how you handle this depends on your implementation.

Comment: okay. so how do i rewrite the above code of mine that is not using Portal to something that uses portal? thanks

Comment: its up to you. do you want to control the portal through another component, or is it just a dom node you need at the top of the tree you can render the popup into as needed? if its the latter, you can use a callback to create the element and append it to the `body`  when your component renders the first time, then render into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned to you in the comment, react doesn't create the dom node for you. You must do it yourself. How you do it depends on your needs. the most basic example i can think of is below:

- When component mounts first time, we need to create the portal and insert it into `document.body`
- once we are sure portal exists, we can render into the portal using our dom ref.

---

```
function Popup({setIsClicked, setSomething, setIsDialogOpen, children}: Props) {

  const [portal,setPortal] = React.useState<HTMLDivElement|null>( (document.getElementById('my-portal') as HTMLDivElement)||null);
  const createPortalIfNotExists = React.useCallback(()=>{
    if(portal===null){
      const el = document.createElement('div');
      el.id='my-portal';
      document.body.appendChild(el);
      // switch this line for the one above if you want it to be first in tree
      // document.body.insertBefore(el, document.body.firstChild);
      setPortal(document.getElementById('my-portal') as HTMLDivElement);
    }
  },[portal]);

  createPortalIfNotExists();

  if(portal===null){
    return null;
  }

  return ReactDom.createPortal(
    <>
        <Overlay
            onClick={() => {
                if (setIsDialogOpen) setIsDialogOpen(false);
                if (setSomething) setSomething(true);
                setIsClicked(false);
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </Overlay>
    </>,
    portal
  );
}
```

This is just one possible way of doing it. There are other more advanced use cases where you would have the portal be rendered by some other element in your component tree. But this should be enough to get you started. Also, i haven't tested this as i don't have tsc/tslint on this machine so YMMV

Comment: thanks a ton it works :) also the setting state for ref thats nice.

Comment: also how to remove this my-portal div on popup component unmount?

Comment: @stack_overflow i would highly advise against doing that, but if you are sure you want to do it, i can update the answer to show how to do so using `useEffect`. the downside will be that everytime your popup hides, the element will be destroyed.

Comment: could you show an example of it. actually the need for me to delete it on unmount was to make sure this div doesnt interfere with other divs on other pages.

Comment: @stack_overflow just to follow up, are you aware that portals automatically remove their content when the rendering component unmounts? because the content of the portal will be destroyed automatically when your popup unmounts. this is because react portals still behave as normal react vdom tree's. when a component unmounts, its content is removed from dom, and the same is true for portals which is extremely convenient. only the container `div` will remain and i don't know why that would interfere. i use portals for all kinds of things, i think they are one of the best react feature.